# How do I convert shapefiles and display them on top of Google Maps?

Tags: shapefile, google-maps, online

I generated a set of maps of my region. Each municipality has some associated data.
I would like to overlay that data on a google map and display them in a website.
(I don't like the flash format)

Do you know any online services for the conversion of *.shp files into a format suitable with Gmap services?

Answer (score 1):

This [article](http://support.google.com/mapsengine/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1272933) should help.

And [ogr2ogr](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) can be used on the desktop to convert the data (reprojecting where necessary)

Comment: link to article redirects to a page which says `Google Maps Engine has been discontinued`. here's the [link](https://web.archive.org/web/20120725014540/http://support.google.com/mapsengine/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1272933) on wayback machine